# Access: query with grouping criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to group data of `Table1` with a query that should give me `Table2` as output.

`Table2.FieldD` is the count of `Table1.FieldB` where the grouping criteria is fulfilled.

The criteria is this:
`Group1` is made by all the record of `Table1` where `Table1.FieldA` starts with "AK" or "KN". `Group2` is the complementary of `Group1`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `iif()`:

```
select iif(fielda like "ak*" or fielda like "kn*", "group1", "group2") as fieldc,
       sum(fieldb)
from t
group by iif(fielda like "ak*" or fielda like "kn*", "group1", "group2")
```

Comment: `SUM(FieldB)` rather than `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  'Group1' AS FieldC
        , SUM(FieldB) AS FieldD
FROM    Table1
WHERE   LEFT(FieldA,2) IN ('AK','KN')

UNION ALL SELECT 'Group2'
                 , SUM(FieldB)
FROM    Table1
WHERE   LEFT(FieldA,2) NOT IN ('AK','KN')
```